# Error with OpenCV Includes

Tags: c++, opencv, capture

See the ticked answer below :)
Error   1   error C2065: 'capture' : undeclared identifier

Using VS2013 Express with OpenCV
Older code examples have worked, but I cant get this one to:

```
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    Mat frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    imshow("Video", frame);
}
```

I had to change `"opencv2/core/core.hpp"`
To `#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>`, and It got that bit.
but I've tried including highgui but I cant get `"capture"` to work?
Any ideas?
x64 on Debug, and using x64 libs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that capture part is a leftover from the old c-api.

try this instead:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    while( cap.isOpened() )
    {
        Mat frame;
        if ( ! cap.read(frame) )
            break;
        imshow("lalala",frame);
        int k = waitKey(10);
        if ( k==27 )
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked, but I was just wondering if capture was literally a variable/Mat container or something, or a function that had to be included.   I guess I can still see the flow and logic behind this method. Thanks

Comment: the old c-api won't be supported in the near future, avoid it.

Comment: it's an [object](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture)

Comment: May I ask, what is that waitKey func doing? is it just waiting for user-input?

Comment: apart from that, it hides the window's message loop / triggers the update / blitting. so - no imshow() without it !

Answer (score 0):

Of course how will it work when you haven't declared the variable `capture`? Probably you want to do something like this:

```
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture("path to video file");
    Mat frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    imshow("Video", frame);
    waitKey();
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
}
```